# Vaadin 7 - Themes compilation

Tags: themes, vaadin, vaadin7

In my application I've more than one theme.
When I try to compile themes it compiles only one theme (the oldest I don't use anymore).
If I cancel that old theme it goes in error.
Where are stored names of themes to be compiled ?
Can I change them ?
Running the application in debug mode it compiles on the fly the correct one.
Tks
Tullio

Answer (score 0):

Partially solved. I found in the plugin configuration the tag theme
and I corrected it. But I didn't find the way to compile more than one theme. Is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

It should compile all the themes by default without needing to configure anything. Have you tried to remove the configuration?